# Как отключить предупреждение о выборе способа оплаты opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.0

Можно убрать сообщение в корзине Вы должны выбрать способ оплаты! в opencart 2.3?
Сами способы я скрыл в отображении. В админке оставил включенным только один способ - Оплата при доставке.
Но еще в контроллере payment_method.php идет проверка на существование способа оплаты

```
$results = $this->model_extension_extension->getExtensions('payment');

  $recurring = $this->cart->hasRecurringProducts();

  foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
      $this->load->model('extension/payment/' . $result['code']);

      $method = $this->{'model_extension_payment_' . $result['code']}->getMethod($this->session->data['payment_address'], $total);
                
      if ($method) {
        if ($recurring) {
          if (property_exists($this->{'model_extension_payment_' . $result['code']}, 'recurringPayments') && $this->{'model_extension_payment_' . $result['code']}->recurringPayments()) {
            $method_data[$result['code']] = $method;
          }
        } else {
          $method_data[$result['code']] = $method;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  $sort_order = array();

  foreach ($method_data as $key => $value) {
    $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
  }

  array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $method_data);

  $this->session->data['payment_methods'] = $method_data;

if (empty($this->session->data['payment_methods'])) {
  $data['error_warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_no_payment'), $this->url->link('information/contact'));
} else {
  $data['error_warning'] = '';
}

if (isset($this->session->data['payment_methods'])) {
  $data['payment_methods'] = $this->session->data['payment_methods'];
} else {
  $data['payment_methods'] = array();
}

if (isset($this->session->data['payment_method']['code'])) {
  $data['code'] = $this->session->data['payment_method']['code'];
} else {
  $data['code'] = '';
}
```

Как я понял в сессию записывается. Можно что-то подставить туда, чтобы он принимал это значение? И в каком оно виде должно быть?